# I do not want my front page sticky post to show up in a category

Tags: sticky-post

I have a welcome paragraph on me front page.  I did this using sticky post.  But the welcome to my website sticky post also shows in my category?   Is there a way to have it show on the front page only?

Comment: yes there is, but few questions before that. where does the category feature, which includes the sticky post?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to instruct the query to ignore sticky posts on category archives.

```
function no_sticky_cats_wpse_125862($qry) {
  if ($qry->is_main_query() && $qry->is_category()) {
    $qry->set('ignore_sticky_posts',true);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','no_sticky_cats_wpse_125862');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in the active theme's **`functions.php`** file to get this done.

```
function wpse_125862_exclude_sticky_post( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category() ) {
        // Will ignore all the sticky posts
        $query->set( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) );
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_125862_exclude_sticky_post' );
```